# Reasons for not allowing me to see my deleted questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

**TLDR**: I have less than 10,000 rep. Why can't I see one of my questions that was deleted by the community?

I had a SO question with 100+ upvotes and 98 favorites. It was deleted for being subjective. I'm fine with that. I don't agree, but I'm fine with it. What chaps my hide is that I'm not even allowed to view the question anymore because I don't have 10,000 rep. I put a lot of time and effort into it and it only seems fair that I could at least view *my own* deleted question.

This post isn't a feature request. This was already [requested and declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645). All I'm looking for is an explanation on *why* it was declined. **Why is allowing people to view their deleted questions a bad thing?**

I did manage to get the content from a mod via email. That's great, but it's the bigger picture that concerns me. Turning down reasonable and popular ([2645](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645) has 200+ upvotes) feature requests with a sound explanation is one thing. But doing so without offering any reasons makes it seem like you're anti-community.

Comment: what are you going to do by watching deleted question ?

Comment: For the record, I don't consider [Jeff's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53297) to [2645](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645) to be an answer at all. He talks about undeleting questions, which wasn't even asked for.

Comment: @Lucifer - I don't want to "watch" it. I want to view the content I contributed. I can view a Closed question, why can I view a Closed question when there's no activity on it either?

Comment: *"I want to view the content"* The work around is to dig it out of a data dump. Or to ask a friendly mod to fetch the text for you if it didn't make it into a data dump.

Comment: @dmckee - Is that the official answer? If, "There's a work-around. Email a mod.", is the answer from up on high - great! Say that when the request is declined. From that answer, I would like to know why I can see questions of mine that have been closed. What's the difference?

Comment: @dmckee - if deleted questions end up in the data dump then what's the harm of **post owners** getting to see their **own** deleted questions like they can with answers. As a mod I find faintly annoying that I can't leave a friendly comment on a deleted question explaining to the OP the error of their ways.

Comment: You're "anti-community" because you make an unpopular decision? Whoa, what are you going to do when Zuckerberg starts putting Facebook content behind pay walls and showing a bunch of banner ads to please his investors?

Comment: But you've read the [FAQ], so you know that it's inappropriate to ask a duplicate question, even if you disagree with the answer there. Try using a bounty, instead.

Comment: @The Establishment - No, I wasn't saying that. I _am_ saying making a unpopular decision _without attempting to offer any reason as to why_ does seem anti-community. Obviously, there's a reason why it's not being done. Maybe they don't have time. If that's the case, _say that_. Believe it or not, I have read the FAQ. I joined almost 4 years ago. I'm not making a feature request, like 2645, I'm asking for an explanation since none was given. If you feel it's a duplicate, vote to close.

Comment: OK, looks like I missed Jeff's "explanation" in the [comments of his answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53297). Maybe, "because people would whine", is the official answer. Is that my answer or has anything changed in the last 2 years?

Comment: @TheEstablishment, i didn't remove the link, the moment, i pressed Save Edits Button, the question was closed by Kev, it was just a co-incident

Comment: Yes, leading to "unbelievable amounts of whining" is probably still the official reason. It's the reason I'm against it, and it's not just theoretical. If you've spent any time at all on Meta, you've *already* seen an unbelievable amount of whining.

Comment: I am not whining, i am just explaining you my self about the reject comment you said. Its ok :) @TheEstablishment

Comment: @Lucifer Sorry, that wasn't directed at you... I missed your comment altogether. Yeah, comparing the timestamps it is pretty clear that your edit collided with the duplicate closure. Sorry about that, if you want to resubmit I'll be happy to approve.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, ok i have edited question again.

Comment: Of course it's not "Official" nor is it necessarily sensible. In the text the OP notes that the particular question he's interested in was deleted after a long life. So it is in some of the data dumps, so he can get it back. That why I said "work around".